# I need a Cassandra Flume Sink

Tags: cassandra, flume, flume-ng, nosql

I am trying to find a template/sample of a Cassandra flume sink. I have looked online, and the two projects I have found on github have outdated dependencies (JARs), and I cant find those artifcats anywhere :(.

Thanks! looking forward for any refs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [stratio-ingestion](https://github.com/Stratio/flume-ingestion) ?

Stratio-ingestion is a flume distribution with some additional source/sinks/morphlines and fix some official bugs.

It also has a [Cassandra Sink](https://github.com/Stratio/flume-ingestion/tree/develop/stratio-sinks/stratio-cassandra-sink) which you can easily inserts your flume events with different configurations.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently working with Stratio-Ingestion. Its really great! Still cant get it to to work though, I am having this error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.Command 

I am not using hadoop, but I set up flume using maven. I think I have to add some dependencies...

Comment: Have you download the release or simply added Cassandra Sink to your distribution?  It's weird because you don't need that class for the Sink.  Maybe you have to import kite-morphlines-core to solve the error. 
Give me more information about how are using the sink.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your custom sink,edit this [cassandra custom sink for flume](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/Flume+NG+Plugins)  cassandra custom sink project to fit your application then clean and build that project,add project jar in flume libs and make your flume configration .